# Setting the viewpoint in ArcGIS Runtime .NET not working (10.2.7)

Tags: .net, arcgis

On mouse click, I am trying to set the viewpoint to a given google map co-ordinate location. When the below code runs, it moves the map to the wrong location at the incorrect scale. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
var point = new MapPoint
(
    -37.808934,
    144.975170,
    SpatialReference.Create(3857)  
);

var extent = new ViewpointCenter(point, 3000);

MyMapView.SetView(extent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my particular case, I was required to convert the co-ordinates in degrees to metres using ConvertCoordinate.FromDecimalDegrees(...) before passing them to the Viewpoint constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Spatial Reference ID to the correct value and use long/lat order:

```
var point = new MapPoint
(
  144.975170, //Longitude first
  -37.808934, //Latitude next
  SpatialReference.Create(4326) //This is the correct code for your coordinates  
);

var extent = new ViewpointCenter(point, 3000);

MyMapView.SetView(extent);
```